# Using WhereRaw on collection ignores relation

Tags: laravel

I made a route to search a particular collection - Customers.

Customer Model

```
public function location() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Location');
}
```

Location Model

```
public function customers() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Customer');
}
```

On the index page, I'm simply showing the customers with the data from `$location->customers()`

`$location` comes from the model route binding.

This is my search controller:

```
if ($request->input('search') != null) {
    $customers = $location->customers();
    
    $search = strtoupper($request->input('search'));
    $searchQuery = 'UPPER(email) LIKE (?) OR CONCAT(UPPER(first_name), " ", UPPER(last_name)) LIKE (?)';

    $customers = $location->customers()->whereRaw($searchQuery, ["%{$search}%", "%{$search}%"]);

    $customers = $customers->paginate();
}

return response()->json(['results' => $customers], 200);
```

When a search is executed, I get 10 times as many results in some cases because it's grabbing all customers rather than the specific location relationship.

How can I make `whereRaw` use the relation?

Comment: What is `$location`? What does your query look like when it's sent to the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the `OR` condition messes up with the query. To avoid that wrap those two query parts with brackets `()`.

```php
$searchQuery = '( UPPER(email) LIKE (?) OR CONCAT(UPPER(first_name), " ", UPPER(last_name)) LIKE (?) )';
```

Eloquent builder approach:

```php
$customers = $location->customers()->where(function($query) use ($search) {
    $query->whereRaw('UPPER(email) LIKE (?)', ["%{$search}%"]);
    $query->orWhereRaw('CONCAT(UPPER(first_name), " ", UPPER(last_name)) LIKE (?)', ["%{$search}%"]);
});
```

**Explanation**

Example logical expression:

`firstCondition && secondCondition || thirdCondition`

In above example expression `thirdCondition` does not even care about `firstCondition` or `secondCondition` because of the `||`.

So if you want to check this `thirdCondition` with `secondCondition`, then you have to explicitly wrap this two conditions with brackets `()`.

`firstCondition && ( secondCondition || thirdCondition )`

This same logic applies for mysql queries too.